# Response On Process Complete

Tags: php

```
<?php
$mysender2= "";
$myrecepient2= "923336088811,923126812536,923134126153";
$mymessage2 = "this is message";
$api_key = "****";
$api_secret="****";

$to_arr = explode(",", $myrecepient2);
foreach ($to_arr as $b){


$url = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?" .
         "api_key=".$api_key. "&" .
         "api_secret="  .$api_secret . "&" .
         "from="  . urlencode($mysender2) . "&" .
         "to=" . urlencode($b) . "&" .
        "text=" .urlencode($mymessage2);





$c = curl_init($url); 

// Use SSL 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$html = curl_exec($c);
curl_close ($c);

}
?>
```

The above script will run again and again untill the process completed . how to show an echo on process complete .. such as "Your Process Completed"

Comment: how is it run again and again? did you mean the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but, your script is so bad and your server goes cry, I know that exists 3 calls only, because your array have 3 values, but if you need more? You will have problems.

The best way in your case is a php header refresh with offset, see bellow:

```
    $offset = isset( $_GET['offset'] ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

    $mysender2= "";
    $myrecepient2= "923336088811,923126812536,923134126153";
    $mymessage2 = "this is message";
    $api_key = "****";
    $api_secret="****";

    $to_arr = explode( ",", $myrecepient2 );

    if( $offset > count( $to_arr ) )
    {
        echo 'Completed!';
    }
    else
    {

        $b = $to_arr[ $offset ];

        $url = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?" .
         "api_key=".$api_key. "&" .
         "api_secret="  .$api_secret . "&" .
         "from="  . urlencode($mysender2) . "&" .
         "to=" . urlencode($b) . "&" .
        "text=" .urlencode($mymessage2);

        $c = curl_init($url); 

        // Use SSL 
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        $html = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close ($c);

        header('Refresh: 0.5; url=YOUR-URL?offset=' . $offset + 1 ); 
                // half a second
    }
```

Comment: Put the URL of this script, example: yourScript.php?offset=..., or, http://www.yoursite.com/yourScript.php?offset=..., or, /path/to/yourScript.php?offset=...

Comment: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@lifetimesms.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.